# Canonical Product URL with category path not showing

Tags: product, url, product-urls, canonical

My webshop is not displaying the canonical product url's with the category path.

I have "Use category path for Product URL's" enabled in the backend but it doesn't seem to work.

Would anybody have any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Did you do a reindex and clear the cache?

Comment: you can get help from here :-https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento

Comment: I have had the option turned on for quite some time. And in between I have reindexed the data but with no succes.

Answer (score 1):

This is Magentos default behaviour.

Because a product can belong to more than one category and magento doesn't know the concept of a "main category" for a product, there is no way to get the "correct" category for the path.

Therefore the path is always without category.

Fixing this means installing an extension or coding it yourself.